ZIO fiber exception lost parent stacktrace on top level catchAll
I'm tracing some error in our production environment. Found cause.squash not give a helpful message.
And I test a demo to see how it output when exception in fiber:
import zio.*

object MainTraceExceptionApp extends ZIOAppDefault {
  case class CustomException() extends Throwable

  override def run: ZIO[Any with ZIOAppArgs with Scope, Any, Any] =
    (for {
      rst <- runLogic()
    } yield {
      rst
    }).catchAllCause(cause => {
//      ZIO.succeed(println(cause.prettyPrint))
//      ZIO.succeed(cause.failures.foreach(_.printStackTrace()))
      ZIO.succeed(cause.squash.printStackTrace())
    })

  def calc(): Task[Int] = {
    for {
      _sleep <- ZIO.sleep(Duration.fromMillis(1000))
      test <- ZIO.fail(new CustomException())
    } yield test
  }

  private def forkAndJoinCalc() = {
    for {
      a <- (ZIO.sleep(Duration.fromMillis(1000)) *> calc()).fork
      _ <- a.join
    } yield {}
  }

  private def runLogic() = {
    for {
      _ <- ZIO.unit
      rst <- forkAndJoinCalc()
      _ = println(s"get rst : $rst")
    } yield {}
  }

}

OUTPUT with cause.prettyPrint:
Exception in thread "zio-fiber-763087962" gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp$CustomException: null
    at gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp$.calc$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$1(ZIOTraceExceptionMain.scala:21)
    at zio.ZIO$.fail$$anonfun$1(ZIO.scala:3225)
    at zio.ZIO$.failCause$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$1(ZIO.scala:3234)
    at gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp.calc(ZIOTraceExceptionMain.scala:21)
    at gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp.calc(ZIOTraceExceptionMain.scala:22)
    at gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp.forkAndJoinCalc(ZIOTraceExceptionMain.scala:27)

OUTPUT with cause.failures.foreach(_.printStackTrace())
gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp$CustomException
    at gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp$.calc$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$1(ZIOTraceExceptionMain.scala:21)
    at zio.ZIO$.fail$$anonfun$1(ZIO.scala:3225)
    at zio.ZIO$.failCause$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$1(ZIO.scala:3234)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:1032)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:1025)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.evaluateEffect(FiberRuntime.scala:403)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.evaluateMessageWhileSuspended(FiberRuntime.scala:477)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.drainQueueOnCurrentThread(FiberRuntime.scala:249)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.run(FiberRuntime.scala:143)
    at zio.internal.ZScheduler$$anon$3.run(ZScheduler.scala:390)

OUTPUT with cause.squash.printStackTrace():
gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp$CustomException
    at gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp$.calc$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$1(ZIOTraceExceptionMain.scala:22)
    at zio.ZIO$.fail$$anonfun$1(ZIO.scala:3225)
    at zio.ZIO$.failCause$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$1(ZIO.scala:3234)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:1032)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:1025)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.evaluateEffect(FiberRuntime.scala:403)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.evaluateMessageWhileSuspended(FiberRuntime.scala:477)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.drainQueueOnCurrentThread(FiberRuntime.scala:249)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.run(FiberRuntime.scala:143)
    at zio.internal.ZScheduler$$anon$3.run(ZScheduler.scala:390)


How to obtain the caller: runLogic and run as expected in catched stacktrace? Thanks
======UPDATE========
I'm found throw new exception after join and wrapper the fiber exception can show the stacktrace. Such as:
  private def forkAndJoinCalc() = {
    for {
      a <- (ZIO.sleep(Duration.fromMillis(1000)) *> calc()).fork
      _ <- a.join.catchAll(cause => ZIO.fail(new RuntimeException(cause.squash)))
    } yield {}
  }

OUTPUT with .tapErrorCause(cause => ZIO.succeed(println(s"cause: ${cause}"))) on run:
cause: Fail(java.lang.Exception: gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp$CustomException,Stack trace for thread "zio-fiber-327737581":
    at gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp.forkAndJoinCalc(ZIOTraceExceptionMain.scala:30)
    at gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp.forkAndJoinCalc(ZIOTraceExceptionMain.scala:31)
    at gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp.runLogic(ZIOTraceExceptionMain.scala:38)
    at gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp.runLogic(ZIOTraceExceptionMain.scala:39)
    at gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp.run(ZIOTraceExceptionMain.scala:13))
timestamp=2024-07-01T07:51:47.795027Z level=ERROR thread=#zio-fiber-1240683466 message="" cause="Exception in thread "zio-fiber-327737581" java.lang.Exception: gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp$CustomException
    at gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp$.forkAndJoinCalc$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$1(ZIOTraceExceptionMain.scala:30)
    at zio.ZIO$.fail$$anonfun$1(ZIO.scala:3225)
    at zio.ZIO$.failCause$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$1(ZIO.scala:3234)
    at gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp.forkAndJoinCalc(ZIOTraceExceptionMain.scala:30)
    at gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp.forkAndJoinCalc(ZIOTraceExceptionMain.scala:31)
    at gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp.runLogic(ZIOTraceExceptionMain.scala:38)
    at gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp.runLogic(ZIOTraceExceptionMain.scala:39)
    at gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp.run(ZIOTraceExceptionMain.scala:13)
    Suppressed: gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp$CustomException: null
        at gs2.ziotest.MainTraceExceptionApp$.calc$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$1(ZIOTraceExceptionMain.scala:23)
        at zio.ZIO$.fail$$anonfun$1(ZIO.scala:3225)
        at zio.ZIO$.failCause$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$1(ZIO.scala:3234)"


I'm wonder does it's the best practice in performance and principles, such as for bussiness logic or library design which using join?

I am not sure what you expect exactly? There is no other exception thrown anywhere so the output seems correct to me.

I think OP was expecting to see runLogic somewhere in the stacktrace.

Yes. Fiber.join will not show parent stacktrace. There should be runLogic call stack on this example but must with catch appened after join.

You can call ZIO#logError to log the error in a ZIO effect. If you want to do something more than that you can tap the effect and log. If you just want to inspect an effect during runtime you can append ZIO#debug on an effect. If you want more info in your log messages you can look into configuring that with zio-logging.

@AlexanderWiklund hi, I'm tested. sorry for ZIO.join.logError not trace parent stacktrace too.
